# Facing Error in WebView android : ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

[image]

[image]

```
  <activity android:name=".main.activity.PaymentWebViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="path" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am redirecting my url to the webview in android . And getting this error, what should I write in my Android manifest file to resolve this error?

Comment: tell me your url which you are passing the webview please

Comment: https://www.mollie.com/payscreen/select-method/pkDUJVHQDB  I am passing this in webview @Ahsan Malik

Comment: Actually I am integrating payment gateway in my applilcation. For that I am using Mollie Api  and getting this as checkout url. I think there is some problem in my manifest file only, but not getting the exact thing what should I place there...

Comment: http://google.com/search?q= add this string before thia url and try and tell me

Comment: https://f50f.dutchgamestudio.nl/mollie/payments/2636ef91-60f9-456c-8c11-dbcaf454ac7d     Actually I am passing this

Comment: And then I am getting this error that is  ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: i think this is not a valid url so please add string mentioned above + your url and try

Comment: What Should I write here     <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="path" /> @Ahsan Malik

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Manifest, you want yo catch `myapp` url scheme but it seems that you received `co.psk.f50f` scheme. There is a mismatch.

Comment: So I should write  co.psk.f50f this instead of myapp  Right?   @Bruno

Comment: yes, you're right : https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: I have referred it already but didnt got it . I have tried many ways ..

Comment: try to remove the `path` attribute

Comment: <data android:scheme="http/"
                     android:host="f50f.dutchgamestudio.nl" />  @ Bruno

Comment: `<data android:scheme="com.psk.f50f" />` Have you read what i've posted ? Have you read the article I've pointed to you ?

Comment: Yes I read....       <data android:scheme="com.psk.f50f"
                    android:host="mollie/payments" /> Right Now I am trying this way

Comment: what will be my prefix

Comment: extract : `In above code replace AppConstants.DEEP_LINK_PREFIX with your url scheme eg.` it means that you have to use `myapp`

Comment: No I think it will be com.psk.f50f

Comment: yes, my bad. If you have the answer, why to you ask ? ;)